# PHP : Foreach Loop Not Starting With Zero

Tags: php

I have this variable :

```
$key = 'text1-text2-text3-021-039-947-927-827-927';
$key = explode ('-', $key);
```

first three of $key `($key[0]...$key[2])` always contains text and it won't be a problem to me. but the rest of it is dynamic.

in that case, the rest of it contains 6 more variables : `$key[3]...$key[8]` but some other case, it can be 10, 9, 2, etc based on user's input.

now the question is... how to echo each key by using FOREACH loop starting with `$key[3]`? not `$key[0]`. thanks.

Comment: `for ($i=3; $i<count($key); ++$i){ }`; `foreach` always starts at the first element.

Comment: Why not remove the first 3 elements before the foreach? Or use a for loop instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
for($i=3; $i<count($key); $i++){
   echo $key[$i];
}
```

Comment: I would use count outside of the loop so it's not getting called every pass through the loop...

Comment: yaa sure, that would be better :).

Comment: @frosty Not that it really makes any noticeable difference.

Comment: i<count($key) should be $i<count($key).

Comment: @NullUserException I agree the difference isn't noticeable in this case, but calculating the count of an array on every pass through the loop isn't necessary. The value of count($key) is not changing, so why not just assign it to a variable outside the loop? Just because there's no noticeable ramifications in a small script doesn't mean it should be done that way. Just my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code you have the key and value

```
$key = 'text1-text2-text3-021-039-947-927-827-927';
$key = explode ('-', $key);


foreach ($key as $k=>$val)
{
   if($k>=3)
   {
     echo "key=".$k ."and value=".$val;
     echo '<br />';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet

```
$isFirst = 1
foreach ($arr as &$value) 
{
    if ($isFirst == 1)
    { 
        $isFirst = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // do code here
    }
}
```

why not use `For Loop`?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = 'text1-text2-text3-021-039-947-927-827-927';
$key = explode ('-', $key);

foreach($key as $count=>$values){
  if($count>=3) {
     echo $values."<br/>";
  }    
}
```

output=>

```
021
039
947
927
827
927
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, but just the heck of it (and because I wanted to provide yet another solution using `foreach`):

```
$key = 'text1-text2-text3-021-039-947-927-827-927';
$key = explode ('-', $key);

array_shift($key); //remove first element..
array_shift($key); //remove second element..
array_shift($key); //remove third element..

//there you go..
foreach($key as ..)
```